# How to remove the Whitespaces from a link

Tags: .net, windows, email, c#-4.0, outlook

This may be a very small issue but honestly I don't know what's the fix, I am writing an application where right click on a file I generated link and send to some email addresses using outlook,  this generated email link has to be the Email Body and this works fine if the generated link does not contain any space. Like If my file name is `"This is a testing file.txt"`, then the generated link will be

```
https://..../share/78/publicLinkHtml/This%20is%20a%20testing%20file.txt
```

but when this email body  got render into outlook email body as

**Download File Link**

```
https://..../share/78/publicLinkHtml/This is a testing file.txt
```

So the link got broken

The way I am doing is this

```
strBody = "%0D%0A";
strBody += strDownloadLink + "%0D%0A";
            strBody += "%0D%0A";
```

While debugging I check that `strDownloadLink` contains %20 characters in the place of spaces but in email body it got removed.

Any idea how can I solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many many thanks to @Donal who gave me idea about the solution, I was busy with HTML formating with `"%0D%0A" or <p></p>`  So fool I am !

but the actual solution is slightly different, instead of using HTML encoding we can do this in slightly different way.

.Net itself is having very good API which constructs any string to URI string, What I did is put that string into `EscapeUriString();`

Code

`strDownloadLink = System.Uri.EscapeUriString(strDownloadLink);`

And then I put that into

```
strBody = "%0D%0A";
strBody += strDownloadLink + "%0D%0A";
strBody += "%0D%0A";
```

After using this the link is fine and no break.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you need to use HtmlEncode:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
Server.HtmlEncode(strDownloadLink, writer);
String encodedString = writer.ToString();
```

For more info see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axh0xdh1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: What is server here? mysql server. I am not using it

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the plain text MailItem.Body property, use MailItem.HTMLBody property and supply an HTML string with the properly constructed `<a>` HTML element.